# show this inequality with the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials

if $n>20$,I have prove let $x_{i}>0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$,and such
$$x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=n$$

show that
$$F(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^3_{i})\le n$$

and find all  other postive integers $3\le n\le 19$

I want use
$$F\left(\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2},\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2},x_{3},\cdots,x_{n}\right)-F(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})=x_{3}x_{4}\cdots x_{n}\left(\dfrac{(x_{1}+x_{2})^2}{4}\left(\dfrac{(x_{1}+x_{2})^3}{4}+\sum_{i=3}^{n}x^3_{i}\right)-x_{1}x_{2}\sum_{i=1}^nx^3_{i}\right)$$
if we show that
$$\left(\dfrac{(x_{1}+x_{2})^2}{4}\left(\dfrac{(x_{1}+x_{2})^3}{4}+\sum_{i=3}^{n}x^3_{i}\right)-x_{1}x_{2}\sum_{i=1}^nx^3_{i}\right)\ge0$$
or
$$\dfrac{(x_{1}+x_{2})^5}{16}-x_{1}x_{2}(x^3_{1}+x^3_{2})+\sum_{i=3}^{n}x^3_{i}\left(\dfrac{(x_{1}+x_{2})^2}{4}-x_{1}x_{2}\right)\ge0$$
or
$$\dfrac{(x_{1}-x_{2})^2}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}(x_{1}+x_{2})(x^2_{1}-10x_{1}x_{2}+x^2_{2})+\sum_{i=3}^{n}x^3_{i}\right)\ge 0$$

Comment: You probably should not reuse $i$ in defining $F$.

Comment: You definitely need to add parentheses in the definition of $F$.

Comment: Explicitly, please use different indices of summation in the $\prod$ and in the $\sum$.

Comment: The inequality should have the same degree of "homogenity"... Which is the inequality explicitly in the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$?

Comment: @function sug, you really should make a point to be precise when first writing out your question.

Comment: @Mike,oh,Ikown it,and  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

$$
n=2 \\
x_1 = 0.4 \\
x_2 = 1.6
$$

This meets the basic conditions.

$$
\begin{align}
F() & = ( 0.4 \times 1.6 ) \times ( 0.4^3 + 1.6^3 ) \\
& = 0.64 \times ( 0.064 + 4.096 ) \\
& = 0.64 \times 4.160 \\
& = 2.66240 \\
\end{align}
$$

This fails the inequality.

Note that this answer, and the comments following, predate adding the $n>20$ clause to the question.

Comment: Oh,Thanks,$n=3,4,\cdots,19$ which is true?

Comment: I have counterexamples for n=3, 4.  It turns out  $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_{n-1}$.  I'm working on a more general program to find more, and with more precision.

Comment: My new program found counterexamples up to $n=10$.  After that, the pattern of $x_1 = x_2 = ... x_{n-1}$ finds them $ = 1$.  With five digits of precision, two interestingly round numbers happen.  For $n=2$, the maximum $F$ appears to be $8/3$.  For $n=10$, the maximum appears to be at $x_1=5/6$ and $x_{10} = 2.5$

Comment: you mean is $n\le 10$ this inequality can't true?

Comment: for $n \leq 10$, this inequality is not true for all $x_1,...x_n$.  For any n, there are $x_i$ values for which the inequality is true.  It may or may not be always true for larger $n$ values, and I only tested my pattern to $n=30$, and there may be other patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is true for any $n\geq11.$

By the Vasc's EV Method, see

https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf corollary 1.8 b),

it's enough to prove it for equality case of $n-1$ variables.

Let $x_1=x_2=...=x_{n-1}=x$ and $x_{n}=n-(n-1)x,$ where $0<x<\frac{n}{n-1}$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$x^{n-1}(n-(n-1)x)((n-1)x^3+(n-(n-1)x)^3)\leq n$$ or $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=\ln{n}-(n-1)\ln{x}-\ln(n-(n-1)x)-\ln\left((n-1)x^3+(n-(n-1)x)^3\right),$$ which is smooth.

By the way, a proof for $n=11$ looks nice enough.